# coldfusion string to function or dynamic cfc

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am working on a code generation project that I would like to dynamically create structs with functionality. I have found you can define functions for a struct, but I want to dynamically generate the name, return value, and any statements inside of the function. I figured a string would allow me to do this but I can't figure out how to convert a string to a function. Is this possible, if not, is it possible to dynamically generate a CFC?

```
<cfset j = structnew()>
<cfset j.test = evaluate('function(){ return "test"; }')>
<cfdump var="#j#">
<cfabort>
```

Comment: I don't like this approach. I just don't a reason where functions come into and out of existence. I normally think of variables changing, but not functions.

Comment: @JamesAMohler it's not that the function changes often, but using a common structure to define the function. IE defining my functions info inside of a json object, and then being able to generate that same function in javascript, coldfusion, c#, or any other language that i want (as long as i have wrote a generator for that language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically create a .cfc the same way you can dynamically create a .cfm.

Step 1 - create the file content as a string variable.

Step 2 - use cffile to write the file.

Step 3 - bring the file into your page.  With .cfm files this would be a `<cfinclude>` tag.  With .cfc files, maybe a createObject (function)

Step 4 - use the code in the file.

Step 5 - delete the file.